# In a sexual context, what does 出せる imply?

Tags: words, context

I got one question - in a text, both characters are talking about the first sexual experience of character one. He tells his friend how it was, and then the friend asks some questions.

It goes: 気持ちよかった？ then イケた？ and then 出せた？

So - my first thought was - that 出せた in this case meant "Did you cum/ejaculate" - ikeru before that also implies cumming but more in a "did you have an orgasm" kind of sense, right? So is there any possibility that 出せた in this occasion could also mean "Did you pull it out"?

If someone could help me clarify that, would be great! Thanks a lot and sorry for the sexual content :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first thought is correct. 行く is "coming" and 出す is ejaculating. Assuming these questions are addressed to a male person, these two indeed refer to the same phenomenon. Simply, this person asked the same thing in two different ways.